# Can a foreign resident apply for a US passport in the US?

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens

My child is a US citizen (dual national) who lives outside of the US. Can I renew their passport (DS-11, as they are a minor) in the US (for example, while visiting) and have the passport sent to the foreign address? If so, can it be done at an acceptance facility? Is there any way to have it sent via tracked mail?

I understand that while technically they must have a US passport to leave the US, [this is not enforced](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/111814/32104) and they would be able to board the flight with their foreign passport.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, unless the foreign country in question is Canada. According to the instructions on the DS-11 form, the US government will not mail a passport to a private address outside the US or Canada. You can apply for a passport at the embassy or consulate in your country of residence, apply for an expedited service while you are in the country, or have the passport mailed to a trusted address in the US.

Comment: You can have them send the passport to a US address run by a package forwarding company like Shipito or Stackry and they'll send it where needed. Ordinarily I'd also recommend doing this through the proper channels, but given the current Covid backlogs, it's acceptable to cut some corners if you want it in a reasonable timeframe IMO.

Comment: @Eugene exactly. Currently, applying for a passport at our local embassy can take months or more.

Comment: @YosefWeiner are you sure? I ask only because I have been a US citizen living outside the US all my life, and have renewed my US passport in Greece, France and the UK. The only one that took a few days (specifically around 4 weeks) was when I renewed it in the UK this year since apparently they had to mail it to the US. When I did this in France and Greece (although this was around 10 and 20 years ago respectively) it was much, much faster, so I thought it was Covid affecting things. Does it really take _months_ for you?

Comment: @terdon, Most consulates process passports pretty quick once they have the paperwork, the problem is the time to get an appointment (which the OP needs) is highly variable. Just picking a few, in Bermuda you can get an appointment 12 days from now but in Mexico City and Tel Aviv there are none available for at least 3 months (they aren't scheduling beyond October yet, apparently).

Comment: @terdon Covid really did a number on the entire federal bureaucracy. I don't know about passports specifically, but last week I phoned to find out what was going on with my Nexus renewal, which only took a couple weeks to get in the first place and they had a warning right in the voice menu:"we're working thorough our Covid backlog, the wait time for Nexus is currently 12-14 months". I imagine the situation with passports is similar.

Comment: Exactly what @Dennis said. My local consulate is Tel Aviv.