# Can I obtain a US passport for my baby if father is not available?

Tags: air-travel, us-citizens, mexico

I'm a single parent and US citizen and want to apply for my baby's passport. However, the father of my child is not in our lives ever since the baby was born and has not been responsible for any of the baby's needs. The nationality of the baby father's is Mexican with only their visa. I have not filed anything in court since he does not want to have any of the baby's responsibility. I know this does not guarantee to get my baby a passport, but is it possible? I have the hospital bills which my parents took responsibility in paying, would that help too?
Forgot to mention my baby is a US  Citizen as well.

Answer (score 19):

If you are the only parent taking care of the child, you should apply for a court order granting you sole custody of the child.  If you have this, [you can apply for the child's passport without needing anything from the father](https://au.usembassy.gov/minors-passports/#:%7E:text=U.S.%20passport%20regulations%20require%20the,sign%20the%20passport%20application%20form.).

If you are unwilling or unable to do this, you will need to submit a [Form DS-5525 "Statement of Exigent/Special Family Circumstances"](https://eforms.state.gov/Forms/ds5525.pdf) explaining why the father is not reachable.  But I would recommend you go for the court order instead, it will simplify many other things as well.

Comment: Thank you, i have filled out the DS5525 form and hope for the best.

Comment: You *really* should get that court order, it's a small hassle now but it can prevent many, much larger hassles later.

Comment: @MichelleFranco among other things, this court order would protect you if you are traveling internationally and you are asked whether you have the father's permission to travel alone with the child.  With a court order granting you sole custody, there is no need for permission.  The same would be true of anything else that usually requires permission from both parents.

Comment: @MichelleFranco You really need that court order granting you sole custody, otherwise the father of the baby can do all sorts of unpleasant things to you and even just bureaucrats trying to look out for the child could put you in very unpleasant situations. One parent "stealing" a child from the other parent is a thing. You don't want to be mistaken for such a parent. You don't want to suddenly end up in a custody battle with a man who would clearly not make a good father. Get sole custody now.

Comment: @MichelleFranco Also read this: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111812